# Planes of Simultaneity on Minkowski diagrams

Tags: special-relativity

As seen from a "stationary" reference frame, Why do lines of simultaneity for fast-moving observers run parallel to distance axis instead of perpendicular to the time axis. Obviously, in a regular t vs x diagram, both are true because the angle between the axes is 90 degrees, but for moving observers the angle between the two axes is not 90 degrees. I can't seen to conceptually understand why. Had I not looked it up, I would have assumed that lines of simultaneity run perpendicular  to the "slanted" t' axis.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.

Answer (score 3):

The plane of simultaneity in a particular observer's reference frame is defined to be the set of events which *that observer* views as simultaneous, i.e. the events that *he* observes to be "orthogonal to the time axis".*

He does not care what *you* think is orthogonal to his time axis. His plane of simultaneity is defined in his reference frame and then maps to whatever plane it maps to in your reference frame.

*This is a horrible way to think about relativity, but we will go with it

Answer (score 0):

On a t vs x diagram, the t'-axis is tilted at an angle of $\arctan(v/c)$ with respect to the t-axis. A line of simultaneity for the moving observer makes an angle of $\arctan(v/c)$ with the x-axis. As a result the line of simultaneity(also called the x' axis) makes an angle of $90^{\circ}-2*\arctan(v/c)$ with the t'-axis which is less than $90^{\circ}$. So the angle between the two axes is not $90^{\circ}$ but less. In order to prove that a line of simultaneity makes the said angle with the x-axis you can refer to the book Special Relativity by A.P. French. A little bit of geometry will of course be called for.